# Error in implementing Cassandra Trigger

Tags: triggers, cassandra

Was trying to implement the triggers in Cassandra.

Have been trying to use the available Cassandra help: https://github.com/hmsonline/cassandra-triggers

However, when i tried to set the value for the trigger and checked the logs, following is the error which i received.

```
DEBUG [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:07:27,753 CassandraServerTriggerAspect.java (line 69) Mutation for [triggers] with consistencyLevel [ONE]
DEBUG [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,873 ConfigurationStore.java (line 66) Refreshing trigger configuration.
DEBUG [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,876 ConfigurationStore.java (line 92) Triggers.isCommitLogEnabled? [true]
DEBUG [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,876 CassandraServerTriggerAspect.java (line 69) Mutation for [world] with consistencyLevel [ONE]
DEBUG [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,882 LogEntryStore.java (line 84) Host ID: CTSINGMRGTO
DEBUG [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,882 CassandraStore.java (line 59) Did not create [triggers:CommitLog_CTSINGMRGTO] (probably already there)
 INFO [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,884 CassandraStore.java (line 93) Did not create [triggers:CommitLog_CTSINGMRGTO] (probably already there)
 WARN [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,884 CommitLog.java (line 38) Instantiated commit log [CommitLog_CTSINGMRGTO]
DEBUG [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,886 TriggerTask.java (line 32) Spawning [20] threads for commit log processing.
DEBUG [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,890 CommitLog.java (line 41) Started Trigger Task thread.
ERROR [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,892 CassandraServerTriggerAspect.java (line 61) Could not write to cassandra! Method: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.doInsert()
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.UUID cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at com.hmsonline.cassandra.triggers.dao.CommitLog.writePending(CommitLog.java:63)
        at com.hmsonline.cassandra.triggers.CassandraServerTriggerAspect.writePending(CassandraServerTriggerAspect.java:72)
        at com.hmsonline.cassandra.triggers.CassandraServerTriggerAspect.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$com_hmsonline_cassandra_triggers_CassandraServerTriggerAspect$com_hmsonline_cassandra_triggers_CassandraServerTriggerAspect$writePending(CassandraServerTriggerAspect.java:1)
        at com.hmsonline.cassandra.triggers.CassandraServerTriggerAspect.writeToCommitLog(CassandraServerTriggerAspect.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.doInsert(CassandraServer.java:854)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.internal_insert(CassandraServer.java:624)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.insert(CassandraServer.java:645)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$insert.getResult(Cassandra.java:3526)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$insert.getResult(Cassandra.java:3514)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:199)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 WARN [Thread-23] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,895 TriggerTask.java (line 62) Could not execute triggers [null]
ERROR [Thrift:2] 2013-03-19 15:08:08,896 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 217) Error occurred during processing of message.
```

For further diagnosis, the error displayed in the *cassandra-cli* is:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_insert(Cassandra.java:839)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.insert(Cassandra.java:823)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeSet(CliClient.java:975)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStatement(CliClient.java:218)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processStatementInteractive(CliMain.java:210)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:337)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the log information given by you, it is clearly mentioned

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.UUID cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

For a better response, you have to share the script and insertion code

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply...i am not very conversant with Java either..
However, as I have already mentioned, i found this error while trying to run the example commands given in that Cassandra help page for triggers: [Cassandra  Triggers](https://github.com/hmsonline/cassandra-triggers/wiki/GettingStarted)
and the commands that i executed are same as given in that page..
The error pops up only when i try to run the last command:
`set hello['test']['triggers']='123';`

Comment: actually it is not a script, i just tried to implement it from the Cassandra client prompt. The commands are:
`create keyspace world;
use world;
create column family hello with column_type = 'Standard' and comparator = 'UTF8Type' and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type' and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type';
set hello['test']['triggers']='123';
use triggers;
set Configuration['CommitLog']['enabled']='true';
create column family Triggers with column_type = 'Standard' and comparator = 'UTF8Type' and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type' and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type';`
<contd.>

Comment: `set Triggers['world:hello']['com.hmsonline.cassandra.triggers.TestTrigger']='enabled';
use world;
set hello['test']['triggers']='123';`

Comment: @Tanny set hello['test']['triggers']='123'; is executed perfectly in cassandra-cli. Better you check your code again, and find out where you have passed UUID? for which columnfamily? field?? Basically the exception is the result of inserting a UUID column value or key value for the field which is assigned integer in its metadata.

Comment: thanks for your time, actually that is the catch, you can set it once, try to set the value again, then it throws the error that i posted, in short, not able to initiate the trigger somehow...

Comment: There is no point it will throw the error, if we repeat the statement, its like updating the row. Further i have tried the same, its not throwing any error.

Comment: so now i realize, there is some build error in my case...
cause updation should not throw any error....I will now start afresh...
can you plz help me what all you did to build, so i dont make any mistakes..

Comment: i haven't done anything out of the box, just remember before starting again from root level clean up all the traces.